# Query filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I don't think this is possible but I wanted to make sure.

Lets say I wanted to get the average age of users assuming some conditions.

```
SELECT avg(age) as avg_a FROM users where something something;
```

Now the say the client wants to get average age, average age for male and average age for female.

so something like

```
SELECT avg(age) as avg_a, avg(age where female) avg_f, avg(age where male) avg_m FROM users where something something;
```

Is something like this even possible or even wise?

How would I go about doing it? Or should I just run 3 queries every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a case statement within your aggregation function. See:

```
SELECT
    avg(age) avg_age,
    avg(case when gender = 'M' then age end) male_avg_age,
    avg(case when gender = 'F' then age end) female_avg_age
FROM users;
```

Comment: Oh my sweet jesus! And it only works on the original subset of the where too!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  avg(age) as avg_a, 
  avg(select age from users where female) avg_f, 
  avg(select age from users where male) avg_m 
FROM users 
WHERE something something;
```

Comment: I don't think that will have the same where clause as the main query though? Will that only work on the subset of the main query?

Comment: true, he would need to add that sub query as well. good point

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the average per gender and the average for all you will have to use the WITH ROLLUP clause in a GROUP BY.

For example, here is some sample data:

```
use junk
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people;
CREATE TABLE people
(name VARCHAR(20),age INT,gender CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO people VALUES
('rolando'  ,46,'M'),
('pamela'   ,40,'F'),
('carlik'   ,23,'M'),
('javonne'  ,22,'M'),
('dominique',15,'F'),
('diamond'  ,13,'F');
SELECT * FROM people;
```

This is the query you need:

```
SELECT IFNULL(gender,'ALL') gender,AVG(age) average_age
FROM people GROUP BY gender WITH ROLLUP;
```

Here is the output:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE people
    -> (name VARCHAR(20),age INT,gender CHAR(1));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO people VALUES
    -> ('rolando'  ,46,'M'),('pamela'   ,40,'F'),
    -> ('carlik'   ,23,'M'),('javonne'  ,22,'M'),
    -> ('dominique',15,'F'),('diamond'  ,13,'F');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM people;
+-----------+------+--------+
| name      | age  | gender |
+-----------+------+--------+
| rolando   |   46 | M      |
| pamela    |   40 | F      |
| carlik    |   23 | M      |
| javonne   |   22 | M      |
| dominique |   15 | F      |
| diamond   |   13 | F      |
+-----------+------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IFNULL(gender,'ALL') gender,AVG(age) average_age
    -> FROM people GROUP BY gender WITH ROLLUP;
+--------+-------------+
| gender | average_age |
+--------+-------------+
| F      |     22.6667 |
| M      |     30.3333 |
| ALL    |     26.5000 |
+--------+-------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Another query style would have been:

```
SELECT A.avgage avg_a,F.avgage avg_f,M.avgage avg_m FROM
(SELECT AVG(age) avgage FROM people) A,
(SELECT AVG(age) avgage FROM people WHERE gender='F') F,
(SELECT AVG(age) avgage FROM people WHERE gender='M') M;
```

Here is that output:

```
mysql> SELECT A.avgage avg_a,F.avgage avg_f,M.avgage avg_m FROM
    -> (SELECT AVG(age) avgage FROM people) A,
    -> (SELECT AVG(age) avgage FROM people WHERE gender='F') F,
    -> (SELECT AVG(age) avgage FROM people WHERE gender='M') M;
+---------+---------+---------+
| avg_a   | avg_f   | avg_m   |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 26.5000 | 22.6667 | 30.3333 |
+---------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Give it a Try !!!